# Binary Matrix with constant row and column sum contains a permutation matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, polyhedra

The following problem was given as a homework problem, so I am not necessarily asking for a full solution, but rather a good hint on where to start.

A chess board, where some of the $64$ cells contain a piece, has the property that every row and every column contains $3$ pieces exactly. I need to show that one can remove some pieces, such that the resulting matrix has exactly one piece in every row and every column.

I feel like this must have an easy solution, but I have not been able to guess it. To give a little bit of context, this problem was given in relation to totally unimodular matrices and integrality of polyhedra.

Comment: You can post your answer as an answer. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I actually found a possible solution myself. By identifying the matrix as a (3,3) biregular graph with 8 vertices on each side of the bipartition, one can see that there is a noninteger solution for the equations

$$x(\delta(v)) = 1 \ \forall v \in V$$
$$x(e) \geq 0 \ \forall e \in E$$

By Birkhoff's theorem, the set of solutions to these equations equal the perfect matching polytope, therefore there exists a perfect matching of our graph and hence a configuration of the chess board, which resembles a permutation matrix.